# Is it possible to link 2 different cells to a ComboBox in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I have a ComboBox that's linked to a cell, R2. It outputs whatever value is entered into it in R2, but what I'd like (if even possible) would be to have the ComboBox output the value to two different cells, ie., R2 and S2, where the value that was input into the ComboBox would output in both of those cells. Is this doable?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't have the formula for cell S2 be `=R2`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking for, I got it to work by referencing the cell ("R2" just like you did. Changing the text in the box also changes the text in R2.
Then, I added this code to Visual Basic, and it is changing them both.

```
    Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("S2").Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value
    End Sub
```